# Change a specific word from a translated string using gettext filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, wordpress-hook

I need to change a specific word from a translated string with variables. I'm using Spanish version of WooCommerce and don't know the exact way as it appears in the english version... but I assume, that it's not relevant to get the point.

I tried using using this kind of code snippet that works fine for a long time:

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text )
    
     case 'Sample' :
     $translated_text = __( 'Example!' );
     break;}    

return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

On WooCommerce when adding to cart a product that is exceeding the available quantity, you get the message (in spanish): *"No puedes añadir esa cantidad al carrito - tenemos 9 **existencias** y has añadido 9 en tu carrito."* (I suppose that in english is something like: *"You cannot add that quantity to the cart - we have 9 in stock and you have added 9 to your cart."*), where "9" is variable... and that's why I couldn't translate all the string using the `gettext` filter hook.

I am trying to change the word **"existencias"** by the string **"unidades en stock"**.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead using `strpos()` and `str_replace()` php functions:

```php
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_add_to_cart_not_enough_stock_message', 10, 3 );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'change_add_to_cart_not_enough_stock_message', 10, 3 );
function change_add_to_cart_not_enough_stock_message( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    // Singular (I don't know if this one will work)
    if ( strpos( $translated_text, 'existencia y has añadido' ) !== false ) {
        $translated_text = str_replace('existencia y has añadido', 'unidad en stock y has añadido', $translated_text);
    }
    // Plural
    if ( strpos( $translated_text, 'existencias y has añadido' ) !== false ) {
        $translated_text = str_replace('existencias y has añadido', 'unidades en stock y has añadido', $translated_text);
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

It could work.

For info the sentence to translate is located [here in `WC_Cart` `add_to_cart` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1203) on line `1203`:

```php
sprintf( __( 'You cannot add that amount to the cart &mdash; we have %1$s in stock and you already have %2$s in your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $product_data->get_stock_quantity(), $product_data ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $products_qty_in_cart[ $product_data->get_stock_managed_by_id() ], $product_data ) )
```

Related: [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word/4366748#4366748)

Comment: @LoicLoicTheAztec Thank you very much... I really appreciate your help!! For sure, I will give it a try!

I figured that maybe there was a way to set a snippet that would help me (in the future) with other similar translations/corrections, in which I could correct ONE word when necessary, instead of having to modify an entire string ... and To be honest, I can't quite understand why it is so different and complicated than replacing a whole string (!?)

Comment: @LoicLoicTheAztec Thank you very much for your help and interest on my answer!

As soon as the snippet was applied, my site crashed. While I was able to access the frontend (with some inconsistencies), I was no longer able to enter the admin area. It took me a few minutes to remove the entry from phpMyAdmin and reset it manually... but honestly, I didn't dare to apply it again and get a log of the error.

Comment: and basically, because I started from the knowledge that if it works, this patch is too specific and targeted, that it would not solve "this kind of problem"... but only and specifically THIS message from the platform.
As I mentioned later, I think that the ideal would be a function that allows replacing ONE WORD and works in the same "general" way that works the code that I shared in my original post... although at the moment, it only seems to be an impossible! =(

Comment: @Speedbit The function itself doesn't make any issue on last woocommerce version (I have just tested this code, but my test web site is not in spanish)… so there is something else that is making trouble in combination.